# How do I solve a dpkg cyclic dependency?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I was trying to profile some program for which I needed `perf`. It wasn't installed so when I tried to launch (`perf stat ./part1`) it with my executable I got:

```
Command 'perf' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install linux-intel-iotg-tools-common  # version 5.15.0-1015.20, or
sudo apt install linux-nvidia-tools-common      # version 5.15.0-1005.5
sudo apt install linux-tools-common             # version 5.15.0-48.54
```

I then did `sudo apt install linux-intel-iotg-tools-common` which terminated correctly. Then when doing `perf stat ./part1` again I got the following:

```
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.17.15-76051715

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.17.15-76051715-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-5.17.15-76051715-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generic
```

I then performed `sudo apt install linux-tools-generic` and got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900 linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic
  linux-tools-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900 linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic
  linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,558 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy/main amd64 linux-tools-common all 5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4 [229 kB]
Get:2 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy/main amd64 linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900 amd64 5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4 [8,325 kB]
Get:3 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy/main amd64 linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic amd64 5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4 [2,164 B]
Get:4 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy/main amd64 linux-tools-generic amd64 5.19.0.76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4 [1,888 B]
Fetched 8,558 kB in 0s (24.0 MB/s)              
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-common.
(Reading database ... 235995 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~16637910
54~22.04~28340d4_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~2834
0d4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.19.0
-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/acpidbg', which is also in package linux-intel-io
tg-tools-common 5.15.0-1015.20
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900_5.19.0-76051900.202207312230
~1663791054~22.04~28340d4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900 (5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~2
2.04~28340d4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic_5.19.0-76051900.2022
07312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic (5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663
791054~22.04~28340d4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-generic_5.19.0.76051900.202207312230~1663791
054~22.04~28340d4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-generic (5.19.0.76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~283
40d4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791
054~22.04~28340d4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

From now on any call to `sudo apt-get upgrade` would fail. I haven't tried anything too fancy with the command as I think I'm missing something. The output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` yields the following:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900:
 linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900 depends on linux-tools-common; however:
  Package linux-tools-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic:
 linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic depends on linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900; however:
  Package linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-generic:
 linux-tools-generic depends on linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic (= 5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4); however:
  Package linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900
 linux-tools-5.19.0-76051900-generic
 linux-tools-generic
```

I tried to purge and remove all these packages (without forcing flags) but it always fails and I'm afraid to break something. I'm puzzled. How can I remove theses packages and return to a healthy previous state of my package manager?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran `sudo dpkg -P linux-intel-iotg-tools-common` and `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and it seems to be fixed...

Answer (score 2):

Hit the same problem.
Tried the solution in Grapix comment and it worked:

```
dpkg -P linux-intel-iotg-tools-common

apt --fix-broken install
```